# Time series, feat_stl returns error, no change since yesterday when it worked fine

Tags: r, time-series, fable

I'm building a time series model in R, using the FPP package (Forecasting Principles and Practices, 3rd edition). The book is available online and I'm working on time series features, as described here:

https://otexts.com/fpp3/stlfeatures.html

This is what the data looks like:

```
# A tsibble: 10 x 5 [1Q]
# Key:       Region, State, Purpose [1]
   Quarter Region   State           Purpose  Trips
     <qtr> <chr>    <chr>           <chr>    <dbl>
 1 1998 Q1 Adelaide South Australia Business  135.
 2 1998 Q2 Adelaide South Australia Business  110.
 3 1998 Q3 Adelaide South Australia Business  166.
 4 1998 Q4 Adelaide South Australia Business  127.
 5 1999 Q1 Adelaide South Australia Business  137.
 6 1999 Q2 Adelaide South Australia Business  200.
 7 1999 Q3 Adelaide South Australia Business  169.
 8 1999 Q4 Adelaide South Australia Business  134.
 9 2000 Q1 Adelaide South Australia Business  154.
10 2000 Q2 Adelaide South Australia Business  169.
```

The code in the book states:

```
library(fpp3)
tourism |>
  features(Trips, feat_stl)
```

However, this returns an error:

```
Error in `lapply()`:
! Can't convert `X[[i]]`, a double vector, to a function.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I get the same error no matter which time series is used.

All the packages are up to date, so is RStudio. Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

EDIT – adding package information here, as I could not get it to fit in an edit:

```
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
#>  os       macOS Sonoma 14.1.1
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/Chicago
#>  date     2024-03-09
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli           3.6.2   2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  clipr         0.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  digest        0.6.34  2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  evaluate      0.23    2023-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  fs            1.6.3   2023-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  glue          1.7.0   2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  htmltools     0.5.7   2023-11-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  knitr         1.45    2023-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  purrr         1.0.2   2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  R.cache       0.16.0  2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.2   2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  R.oo          1.26.0  2024-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  R.utils       2.12.3  2023-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  reprex        2.1.0   2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  rlang         1.1.3   2024-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  rmarkdown     2.26    2024-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  rstudioapi    0.15.0  2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  styler        1.10.2  2023-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#>  vctrs         0.6.5   2023-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  withr         3.0.0   2024-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  xfun          0.42    2024-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  yaml          2.3.8   2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

(EDIT - I restarted my computers and it ran with no issues on both systems. Not sure why this worked, but the issue is resolved)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Could you please provide a reprex that includes your package versions? You can do this with `reprex::reprex(session_info = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this on two systems, restarted each of them, and everything ran fine, no issues. Problem solved, no further issues.